call decimate function from matlab
I tried to call decimate function in Scipy from Matlab but met an error. Can somebody point me in a direction, please?
Here is a code of Matlab
py.print("Hello, Python!")
% generate a sin signal
clear
fc=2;  % in Hz
f_sampling=100;   %in Hz
t=0:1/f_sampling:3;  %in 3s
y=sin(2*pi*fc.*t);   % signal
plot(t,y)
y_dem=py.scipy.signal.decimate(y,5); 

>> try_python
Hello, Python!
Error using signaltools>decimate (line 4401)
Python Error: TypeError: 'float' object cannot be interpreted as an integer
 


Code did not show line by line. Retype it for easy reading

fc=2;  % in Hz
f_sampling=100;   %in Hz
t=0:1/f_sampling:3;  %in 7ms
y=sin(2pifc.*t);   % signal

sorry, I am not able make it line by line

You can use the {} button to  format text as code. Hover over the buttons and they tell you what they do

Thank you, Hilmar

Matlab uses double values by default.
Scipy.signal.decimate expects an integer as the second argument, the decimation factor.
Explicitly convert your decimation factor to an integer type:
y_dem=py.scipy.signal.decimate(y,int32(5));


Hi Jdip.  It works. Thank you very much for your quick reply.
